# download Authenticated user documents as zip Archive in laravel

Tags: laravel

so this is my function to download the auth user documents but it's downloading all user documents which is not what i want
public function downloadAll(){

```
    // Initialize an instance of the ZipArchive class
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    // create a file to download the zipped files
    $fileName = 'alldocuments.zip';
    //if path to the files exits then add the files and zip them
    if ($zip->open(storage_path($fileName),ZipArchive::CREATE == TRUE))
    {
        //get the authenticatated user documents
        $user = Auth::user();
        $documents = CompanyDocument::where('user_id',$user->id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
        //then add the auth user files to
        $files = File::files(storage_path('app/documents/',$documents));
        foreach ($files as $key=> $value)
        {
            $relativeName = basename($value);
            $zip->addFile($value,$relativeName);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
}
```

Comment: then in my view where all the authenticated user documents is i have something like this  <form action="{{route('user.document.download-all')}}" method="GET">
                                    @csrf
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right float-right mb-2">Download All</button>
                                </form>

Comment: and my route web folder i have something like this             Route::get('/zip', 'CompanyDocumentController@downloadAll')->name('download-all');